# How to synchronize between 2 database and different host in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, synchronization, offline

i had 2 databases, one run in my localhost which is offline and another is in server which is online, and what i want is after i insert some data in my localhost offline, i can click a button in my offline which is sync the database and update it on the server database which is online, and anyone of you know how  to do it? Im new in php and mysql, hope you all can help, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Doing synchronization like this is, I'm sorry to say, not a beginner activity.

If you were more experienced I would recommend things like a transaction table - where you record each action, then replay it on the server (aka slave).

MySQL can also do that automatically see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

But none of it is simple to setup.

If you don't mind deleting and recreating the database fresh each time, then you maybe be able to use `mysqldump` to create a full export of your database, then load it on the server.

Comment: did the replication is php based? and how it code? when i saw read the link you gave, i have no idea how to setup and start T.T

Comment: No, the replication is not php. It's internal to MySQL. Setting it up is long and complicated, sorry, but you will simply have to learn it. You can also try google for some tutorials: https://www.google.com/search?q=setting+up+mysql+replication

Comment: thanks again, what the different between synchronization and replication? replication can function while offline? because what i want is just update one table in database from local to master server

Comment: Synchronization is two way, replication is one way. Replication is much easier.

Comment: what i read is replication can just insert data on master server and slave just can read cannot insert? is this true? because i want to let both can insert new data.

Comment: Yes, that is true. If you need it to go both ways then you need synchronization.

Comment: then the replication no use to me =( because what i need is the local server store data while offline, so when online then the data will sync and save in the online server database

Comment: Offline synchronization is quite hard to do. You will probably need to write this by hand: Store a transaction table that remember every change you make, and sends it to the other server.